# New tag for rests

Tags: discussion, tags

There are a significant number of questions (80+) that are primarily about rests:

[image: list of rest symbols]

These are about the: rhythm, notation, engraving, history, etc. of rests, or about getting them to work with particular software.

**Should we make a new tag for rests?**
Or, is there some good reason that we don't have one already?

---

If agreed, I'll instantiate [rests](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rests) and suggest a tag wiki. But, I'll only begin the process of adding it to old questions when/if [the strike](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3958/general-moderation-strike) ends.

Comment: To simply put it this way, rests are a core part of notation. They can be viewed as the opposite of a note. Every note has a rest equivalent. We do not have a tag for notes, just the overall notation which consists of a majority of notes and rests. Why are we making a tag for one, but not the other and is there any case where the notation tag would not apply?

Comment: I'm also going to say outside whether or not this should be a tag, questions that have rests in them should not automatically be given the tag. The question should be about rests. For example if someone is confused about how to count a rhythm section or if a time signature is appropriate, the rests themself are not really a core part of the question. The rhythm and time signature are.